# Scanner loop that is supposed to return each String,

Tags: java, while-loop

I've got a problem with looping a scanner, wich should return EVERY string given as an input unless `String != "end"`. Here is what I've done so far

```
private static String fetchString() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stringElement = "";
    System.out.println("Write a string");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        stringElement = scanner.next();
        if(stringElement == "end") {
            break;
        }
    }
    return stringElement;
}
```

result:

```
Write a string
abc
abc
abc
end
end
```

Loop, somehow, doesn't understand `if(stringElement == "end")`, it still wants new word. I can't get it. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Please don't annotate Java code as if it were a Javascript snippet - Java and Javascript are very different. Now, you've declared a method that returns a single string - how would you expect that to return multiple strings? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @KevinEsche: That's *a problem* in the code, but it's not the primary one, I'd say.

Comment: To begin with, use `stringElement.equalsIgnoreCase("end")` instead of `stringElement == "end"`

Comment: Also note that you are checking for `hasNextLine` and reading a single String using `next`

Comment: I return string, and then put it to the table

Comment: yes, I have to return ONE string, and then add it to the table, but then I have to repeat that untill `string.equals("end")`

Answer (score 0):

First change, `stringElement = scanner.next();` to `stringElement = scanner.nextLine();`, second change `if(stringElement == "end")` to `if(stringElement.equals("end"))`